# Difference between turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch and turtlebot service?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Turtlebot Bringup wiki doesn't describe what is different between the service and running minimal.launch manually. From my crude digging it seems that the service also runs minimal.launch but with some extra params and an argument added.

1. Is there a difference in methods to launch the Turtlebot?
2. How can I see the terminal output of the service (I often run the manual method just to see what's going on)?
3. Is there a way to remove the service from running at startup (admittedly stupid question but I'm stumped)?

Thanks,
Ryan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28020/difference-between-turtlebot_bringup-minimal.launch-and-turtlebot-service?/) by [Ryan Hickman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1822/ryan-hickman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. There are two ways to start the TurtleBot:

a. Using the linux service:

```
    sudo service turtlebot start
```

The service starts the TurtleBot drivers in the background by launching the turtlebot.launch file located in /etc/ros/electric (or fuerte or whatever distro you are running). The advantage of using the service is that it launches a file in user editable space, so you can configure and change your TurtleBot launch files without changing the debian install. You need to do this when calibrating your robot or changing the URDF when you add an arm or move the sensor locations.

b. Using the default launch file:

```
    roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

This launch file starts the TurtleBot with the default configuration (default URDF and calibration). Typically you should not edit this file because it is the default installation on your computer and typically if you need to add sudo to edit the file then you shouldn't do it.

2. Unfortunately I don't know a good way to look at the output of a launch file running in the background. I recently added status to the turtlebot_dashboard to improve visibility into what was happening in the background.
3. To stop the service from running at startup you need to remove /etc/init/turtlebot.conf. If you look at the install.sh script in turtlebot_bringup/upstart you'll see how the service is installed on your TurtleBot.

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4